# Why am I not experiencing an error when working with strings in Xcode?

Tags: c, arrays

In Xcode I declared a string called `myString` with 5 spaces in memory.

```
int main() {

    char myString[5];

    printf("Insert a string: ");
    scanf("%s", myString);
    printf("Your string is %s.", myString);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that whenever I type a word longer than 4 characters the console still prints out with `printf()` my string instead of complaining about it.

What is this due to?

Comment: FYI - this issue has nothing at all to do with Xcode. It's a "feature" of the C language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, as you've defined `myString` to have 5 `char`s, any input running longer than 4 chars (consider terminating null also as the 5th) will actually cause out of bound memory access, which produces [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The result can be anything, inducing working *normally*, as if you had allocated *enough* memory.

You should be limiting your input using

```
 scanf("%4s", myString);
```

and likewise.

Also, as a note, the recommended signature for `main()` is `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or at least, `int main(void)`.

Comment: Thanks! Then why isn't the compiler complaining instead of printing out the entire string? This sounds very weird.

Comment: @CeceXX The string is inputted by the user at runtime, so the compiler knows nothing about it.  It also doesn't keep track of how big an array is.  You're expected to handle that yourself.

Comment: @CeceXX compiler has no idea about the allocated memory at the supplied pointer and no control over the runtime input, so it has no reason to complain. It is the duty of programmer to ensure buffer overflow does not happen.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! It is much appreciated :-) @Sourav I'm going to accept your answer whenever it lets me. Thanks for editing my question also!

Answer (score 1):

C will happily clobber any memory you hand it.  AKA, a buffer overflow. :-)